# I have a visual C# project and I'm trying to insert data in a MS Access Database when I press a button

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledb

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string str = "insert into Checklist_Master values('"+comboBox2.Text+"','"+txtaurno.Text+"','"+comboBox1.Text+"','"+txtdeduction.Text+"','"+txtceckpoint.Text+"','"+mdlconnection.user_name+"')";
        int dd = mdlconnection.excuteQuery(str);
        //MessageBox.Show(str);
        if (dd > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully..!!!");
            reset();
        }                    
}
```

And connectionstring is :

```
public static void getconn()
{
    con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Learning\\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb");
    con.open();
}
```

This is Excutequery method:

```
public static int excuteQuery(string q)
{ 
     int d = 0;
     try
     { 
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, con); 
         d = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     } 
     catch (Exception e)
     { 
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     } 

     return d; 
}
```

Please help why data is not inserted in table

Comment: What is `excuteQuery` method? It is an extension method? Or you just missing basic methods? And you never use `getconn` method

Comment: public static int excuteQuery(string q)
        {
            int d = 0;
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, con);
                d = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return d;
        }

Comment: @shweta mentioning  this method in your question would be better..

Comment: @shweta Did you debug your code and check your values? You get any exception or error message by the way?

Comment: public static int excuteQuery(string q)
        {
            int d = 0;
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, con);
                d = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return d;
        }

Comment: Ya i have debug my code but i didnt get exception ..I think it is problem related to datatype.I have use text datatype in access for all column & Autonumber for ID..is it ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you never open the connection by call `getconn()`. the connection is never opened.

Secondly, you have to specify the columns for the `INSERT INTO Checklist_Master  (Col1, Col2...) VALUES ()`

Lastly, try setting it up the following way:

```
    using(OleDbConnection oledb = new OleDbConnection(<Your Connection String>))
    {
       oledb.Open();

       using (OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(<sqlString>,oledb)) //the sql passed in as a parameter as your method suggests
       {
           oleComm .CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
           oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

       }

    }
```

You can add the `try catch` as required. Just good practice to clear and close all instantiated objects. You can also try and replace the variables in the `INSERT` statement with parameters

```
INSERT INTO Checklist_Master (<Col>,<Col2>,...) VALUES (@Param1,@Param2);

oleComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", comboBox2.Text); //Conversion if required
```

Comment: Great. Please mark green if you are happy.